# cursor is visible not matter what my code says

Tags: unity-game-engine, cursor, toggle

hey so originally i made this pause menu script and it make my cursor visible but it doesn't turn the cursor off i even made the script on/off seperate codes at one point but it still dosnt turn the cursor off. any one have any idea why? thanks. and i haven't written enough so here are some words to read so i hope you enjoy them i put no effort into these here words

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PMScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public GameObject VolumeSettings;
    public GameObject mainSettings;
    public GameObject GraphicsSettings;
    public GameObject HitMarker_;
    public GameObject pmui;


    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (VolumeSettings == true)
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }

        if (mainSettings == true)
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }

        if (GraphicsSettings == true)
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            HitMarker_.SetActive(false);
            pmui.SetActive(true);
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }

        if (VolumeSettings == false)
        {
            if (mainSettings == false)
            {
                if (GraphicsSettings == false)
                {
                    if (pmui == false)
                    {
                        Cursor.visible = false;
                        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried hiding the cursor without any of the conditions? Once you have the cursor hiding without any other logic, try re-implement each of the `if` statements one by one until you find where the problem is

Comment: When you compare a `GameObject` with a bool like this: `VolumeSettings == true`, what you're checking is whether or not `VolumeSettings` is assigned in the inspector. If this is intentional make sure that `VolumeSettings`(along with the others) is not assigned if you want the cursor to be locked.

Comment: @DekuDesu how would i check if the game object is active or inactive then?

Comment: You could use `If(VolumeSettings.activeSelf == true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare a `GameObject` with a `bool` such as

```cs
VolumeSettings == true
```

What you're checking is whether or not `VolumeSettings` is assigned in the inspector.

If this is intentional make sure that `VolumeSettings`(along with the others) is not assigned if you want the cursor to be locked.

If you're instead trying to check whether the `GameObject` is active or not consider using the following

```cs
if(VolumeSettings.activeSelf == true)
```